# Can a node have a property twice?

Tags: neo4j, property-graph

I would like to create a database with abbreviations for every word used in my company.

Can I define a various number of properties for the same property (as in RDF)?
Is it possible to use different data types?

for example like this:

```
:Word
Name: Airbus A380
Abbreviation: A380
Abbreviation: 380
Abbreviation: xyz

:Word
Name: House
English: House
English: Home
Spanish: Casa
German: Haus
German: Wohnung
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a property can only occur once on a node and have a single value. You can make the property value a list of strings, but you won't be able to look these up via an index.

You might consider separate :Abbreviation nodes connected to your :Word nodes, match from the abbreviations to the word.